# Git migration: copy commits from one repo to an another including merge commits and preserve history

Tags: git, version-control, merge, migrate, svn2git

Our project recently(~4 months ago), moved from SVN to git. Our initial migration was done by a guy, who had basic git knowledge. Our git repo is a bit chaotic now(there is a commit where 1million file was deleted, the diff is like 25G).

I would like to repair the git repo as blame exits with out of memory error, not to mention sonarqube takes ages to run.

**The project layout was:**

We had several modules in subdirs under the svnroot.

```
svnrepo/
  module1/
    trunk
    branches/
      ...
    tags/
      1.x
      ...
  module2/
    trunk
    branches/
      ...
    tags/
      1.x
      ...
```

*Now* we have a "big" git repo where all the modules are subdirs.

I could not import the whole svnroot(I was interested in trunks only), and tried several tools including git svn, but did not work.

I've read a question about the same problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/420828/migrate-multiple-svn-repositories-into-single-git-repository

**What I have done:**

Managed to import subdirs(used svn2git rubygem) as git repos, and used filter branch to move files in subdirs, and merged everything in develop. 
I have checked out the old repo after the 1 million file has been deleted. This is the base.

**The problem:**

In order to replace our currently "broken" repo, I need to make sure, every commit is done after git migration, will be migrated to the new repo.

I have tried to cherry pick commits, but looks like, I will lose the history, as it only preserve the diff of the merge commits.

**The question is:**

How can I migrate commits(from old the repo, after that particular commit) to a new repo in a way where branches and merge commits and all of their history will be copied over as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you're intentionally trying to get the multiple SVN repos into a single git repo, I think you're causing yourself some long-term grief, and would be better off creating a repo per module.

You can then use subtrees, submodules, or another mechanism to pull the modules down and use them together.

Comment: I've been told, that subtree and submodules can cause issues so I we rather did not use it.

The problem is: we have a single git repo now, and we have been working in this repo for like months, we don't want to lose commit history.

The question really is: how do I import commits after a certain point of history to this newly created repo(while I preserve merge commits and branches)